# In my robot framework, i want to have the ability to execute my smoke and regression tests separately via Jenkins. How can achieve the same?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, robotframework, build-automation, cicd

In my robot framework, I have 80 test cases which are available in a  git repo. Out of these 80,i want to run 10 test cases as a part of Smoke testing which are tagged as Smoke. Also, if i want to run regression, all 80 test cases should run.

I want to configure a Jenkins job where I should be able to run smoke or regression test cases by choice. It would be great if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How would you manually run this? Can you select the Test cases you want to run using Robot? If so update the question and add how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your 80 test cases have only 10 test cases which have a tag called "Smoke"
If you want to execute smoke test:

```
robot -d result -i Smoke test_cases/
```

if you want to execute regression test (all 80 test cases):

```
robot -d result test_cases/
```